# JXLS. How can I put different collections in different sheets?

Tags: java, jxls

I'm trying to put two collections in a excel document. I'm doing this:

```
context.putVar("collection1", collection1);
context.putVar("collection2", collection2);    
xlsHelper.getInstance().processTemplate(getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("templates/exceldocument.xls"), os, context);
```

The excel document has two sheets, one sheet where are the `collection1` and the other sheet where there are the `collection2`.

But when I do this only one collection are put in one sheet.

How to put two collections in differents sheets?

Answer (score 2):

You can build a list of XLS Areas and process them manually as you wish.
The code can look like this

```
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.createTransformer(is, os);
AreaBuilder areaBuilder = new XlsCommentAreaBuilder(transformer);
List<Area> xlsAreaList = areaBuilder.build();
Area sheet1Area = xlsAreaList.get(0);
Area sheet2Area = xlsAreaList.get(1);
sheet1Area.applyAt(new CellRef("sheet1!A1"), context); // process sheet1
sheet2Area.applyAt(new CellRef("sheet2!A1"), context); // process sheet2
transformer.write();
```

It is actually quite easy to add similar support to *JxlsHelper* so feel free to raise an improvement in [Jxls issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls/issues?status=new&status=open) to improve *JxlsHelper*.

See also [XlsCommentBuilderDemo](https://bitbucket.org/leonate/jxls-demo/src/c5ae177fae1480be45d115045d5d4615a8637f4d/src/main/java/org/jxls/demo/XlsCommentBuilderDemo.java?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default) example code for a more comprehensive example.